# Why list is required just to cancel single pop up in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

In Page Object factory:

```
By popup=By.xpath("//button[test()='NO THANKS']");

public List<WebElement> getPopUpSize(){
return driver.findElements(popup);
}

public WebElement getPopUp(){
return driver.findElement(popup);
}
```

Calling above methods into Testcase:

```
LandingPage l = new LandingPage(driver);
if(l.getPopUpSize().size()>0)
{
l.getPopUp().click();
}
```

I didn't understand why do we have to create a list just to cancel single pop up?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you not understand why you need to check for the presence of the popup? Or do you not understand why `findElements` returns a `List`? Or something else?

Comment: Can you provide more info, on exactly what isn't working, and what the expected output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need `findElements` for a single web element. Use `findElement` instead or `Explicit waits` as illustrated below:

1. Using `ExplicitWaits`

**Code:**

```
public WebElement getPopUpWebElement(){
    return driver.findElement(popup);
}
```

and in test method:

```
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(getPopUpWebElement())).click();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not click on pop up");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```